# Convert std::vector to Rcpp matrix

Tags: r, rcpp

This is an Rcpp conversion related Q. I'm looking to convert a long std::vector into a Rcpp matrix object, but want to know if there is an easy conversion format. Naturally, you could loop over each element and fill an empty Rcpp matrix, but this seems error prone and possibly needless if a more convenient approach is possible.

The reason I'm asking is I would like to utilize OpenMP in some existing C++ code, but storing element in the Rcpp matrix object directly in an OpenMP loop doesn't appear to work well (whereas loading a std::vector object and converting to a matrix after the OpenMP loop is complete seems to be a decent approach to the problem).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You chose a good approach. In the OpenMP context, you have to stay away from the single-threaded R.  So `std::vector` is good.

And yes, we have constructors from `std::vector` to `Rcpp::NumericVector` and `Rcpp::NumericMatrix` (which is after all just a vector with a dimensions attribute) as well as the `Rcoo:Integer*` variants, as well as the usual `as<>` and `wrap` converters.

There should be plenty of examples in the Rcpp unit tests, the Rcpp examples, and of course on the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) site.

*Edit:* Here is an overly simple example:

```
 R> cppFunction('NumericVector phil(int n) { std::vector<double> x(n);
 +              return wrap(x); }') 
 R> phil(4)  
 [1] 0 0 0 0    
 R>
```

Comment: Great, thanks so much Dirk. I didn't see any in the Rcpp gallery or the examples that ship with the package, but maybe I just wasn't looking hard enough...

Comment: I see. Yes I understand that std::vector's are easily converted to Rcpp vectors, but I was more wondering about the most optimal way to fill a NumericMatrix given a std::vector and known dimensions (I guess something more like `NumericMatrix ret = vector2NumericMatrix(x, n, m);`, where `n` and `m` are the number of rows and columns. Easy to write a function to do this of course, but I was more wondering if something like this has been done already. Thanks! And sorry if I'm pestering you about trivial things :)

Comment: You can also consider RcppArmadillo which, as a linear algebra / matrix library, has a tons of subsetting, joining, combining, ... operators.  That would probably be my choice.  We may be missing a converter or two. Contributions welcome.

Answer (score 23):

To expand on Dirk's answer; R matrices are really just vectors with a `dim` attribute set

```
> x <- 1
> y <- as.matrix(x)
> .Internal( inspect(x) )
@7f81a6c80568 14 REALSXP g0c1 [MARK,NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 1 ## data
> .Internal( inspect(y) )
@7f81a3ea86c8 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(2),ATT] (len=1, tl=0) 1 ## data
ATTRIB:
  @7f81a3e68e08 02 LISTSXP g0c0 [] 
    TAG: @7f81a30013f8 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "dim" (has value) 
    @7f81a3ea8668 13 INTSXP g0c1 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0) 1,1
```

Notice how the 'data' component of `x` and `y` are just `REALSXP`s, but you have this extra `dim` component on the matrix. Using this, we can easily convert a `NumericVector` to a matrix in `Rcpp`.

(Note: in the example below, I use `SEXP` in the attributes just so the conversions between types are explicit):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP vec_to_mat(SEXP x_) {
  std::vector<double> x = as< std::vector<double> >(x_);
  /* ... do something with x ... */
  NumericVector output = wrap(x);
  output.attr("dim") = Dimension(x.size(), 1);
  return output;
}

/*** R
m <- c(1, 2, 3)
vec_to_mat(m)
*/
```

gives me

```
> m <- c(1, 2, 3)

> vec_to_mat(m)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
```

So, you can use the `Dimension` class and assign it to the `dim` attribute of a vector to make a matrix 'by hand' in Rcpp.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks!