# RcppArmadillo Compile Errors on OS X Mavericks

Tags: xcode, r, rcpp

This is a follow-up to the question at [Element-Wise Matrix Multiplication in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917023/element-wise-matrix-multiplication-in-rcpp)

I have been getting a number of different kinds of errors with RcppArmadillo since upgrading to Mavericks. I have Xcode 5.0.2 and Command Line Tools installed. Also, gfortran from Homebrew. But I keep encountering the error below --

```
> cppFunction("arma::mat schur(arma::mat& a, arma::mat& b) 
                       { return(a % b); }", depends="RcppArmadillo")


ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sourceCpp_18474.so] Error 1
clang++  -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include  -    I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include"    -fPIC  "-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion" -c fileaf992bfb8f84.cpp -o fileaf992bfb8f84.o clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o sourceCpp_18474.so fileaf992bfb8f84.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -lgfortran /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/lib/libRcpp.a -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation 
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, showOutput = showOutput,  : 
Error 1 occurred building shared library.

WARNING: The tools required to build C++ code for R were not found.

Please install Command Line Tools for XCode (or equivalent).

# Contents of Makevars
$ cat ~/.R/Makevars 
CC=clang
CXX=clang++ 
CXXFLAGS="-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion"
FLIBS=-lgfortran
```

Commenting `FLIBS=-lgfortran` does not help and results in even more error messages --

```
> cppFunction("arma::mat schur(arma::mat& a, arma::mat& b) { return(a % b); }", depends="RcppArmadillo")
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8/4.2.3/x86_64'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/x86_64'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8/4.2.3'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sourceCpp_50381.so] Error 1
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Following suggestions from response from Kevin and Dirk below, I re-installed Rcpp, RcppArmadillo and inline from source and updated FLIBS to point to the actual directory. This solved the issue.

```
# Update FLIBS in ~/.R/Makevars
FLIBS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran
#Re-Install from source
install.packages(c("Rcpp","RcppArmadillo","inline"),type="source")
#Restart R
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT: If you're a Homebrew user, you now instead need to use `brew install gcc` (`gfortran` is no longer provided separate of `gcc`), and you can then follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992066/rccp-warning-directory-not-found-for-option-l-usr-local-cellar-gfortran-4-8/29993906#29993906) to get set up.

---

You have to symlink the libraries to `/usr/local/lib` manually:

`ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.* /usr/local/lib/`

I thought `brew link gfortran` would handle this, but apparently it only symlinks the `gfortran` program and not the actual libraries. So, unfortunately, you have to do it yourself.

(Replace `4.8.2` with whichever version of `gfortran` you're using from `homebrew`.)

---

Alternatively, if you want to keep from modifying `/usr/local/lib`, you can use

```
FLIBS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran
```

in your `~/.R/Makevars` file instead, so R knows where to find the `gfortran` libraries.

Comment: Thanks. Re-installing Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, inline from source and updating FLIBS to point to the actual directory (`FLIBS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran`) resolved the issue. For reference, to install from source -- `install.packages(c("Rcpp", "RcppArmadillo","inline"),type="source")`

Comment: I just encountered a similar problem installing Rserve in a homebrew installed R 3.1.2 on OS X Yosemite: `ld: library not found for -lintl`. Using `locate libintl.a` and then adding a symlink from that location to /usr/local/lib as above fixed the problem.

Comment: `brew install gfortran` yeilds: GNU Fortran is now provided as part of GCC, and can be installed with: brew install gcc.     Do I still need to manually link gfortran after installing it with gcc?

Comment: You'll need to do something similar -- see my (better) answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992066/rccp-warning-directory-not-found-for-option-l-usr-local-cellar-gfortran-4-8/29993906#29993906)

Answer (score 1):

I can only suggest you study the numerous threads on the [r-sig-mac list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.mac), the different answers here on SO as well as the posts on the [rcpp-devel list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.rcpp).

As your error comes from the failed Fortran linking, maybe also review [the standard page by Simon U.](http://r.research.att.com/) as well as the [tools page](http://r.research.att.com/tools/) it points too.  AFAIK you should use the (older) gfortran 4.2.* from that page with R -- but then I am not an OS X user.

*Edit in late 2016:* We now have more detailed instructions in [section 2.16 of the Rcpp FAQ](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the links, I followed the suggestion on one of the questions on the rcpp-devel-list and re-installed Rcpp, RcppArmadillo and inline from source. That resolved the issue.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel. If studying numerous threads on r-sig-mac is usefeul: what do they conclude? If there are different answers on SO which are correct?

What would you conclude from "Simon U" page? What needs to be done from the tools page? If people have moved on from 2008, what can they do regarding fortran support?