# install packages not working after updating R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I recently updated my RStudio and I am unable to install or update any packages. See the error below. Any advise on how to address this issue? My RStudio version is:

```
               _                           
    platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
    arch           x86_64                      
     os             darwin15.6.0                
   system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
    status                                     
   major          3                           
   minor          5.1                         
   year           2018                        
  month          07                          
  day            02                          
svn rev        74947                       
  language       R                           
 version.string R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
nickname       Feather Spray   

     error below----
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘miceadds’
   * removing 
 ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/miceadds’
 * restoring previous 
 ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/miceadds’
 Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘miceadds’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Is that all the output you see from `install.packages`? Usually there is a more descriptive error message earlier in the output. If you updated RStudio, you might want to update R as well. It seem you are running R 3.5 which is a bit out of date.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135703/package-install-error-compilation-failed

Comment: I would first update R, and then try again.

Comment: thank you very much, I updated R and it started working fine!