# Rcpp warning: "directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran'"

Tags: r, rcpp

This question relates to some others out there, like [RccpArmadillo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920281/rcpparmadillo-compile-errors-on-os-x-mavericks) or [element-wise-multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917023/element-wise-matrix-multiplication-in-rcpp).

However, my settings are such that I do not know what I have to edit/simlink to make Rccp run without giving me warnings.

I am on an Mac 10.9 (mavericks) using the latest R version.

At the very beginning, trying the following code I got from here [RccpvsR](http://brainchronicle.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/rcpp-vs-r-implementation-of-cosine.html), I got an error:

```
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
```

Then, based on [RccpArmadillo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920281/rcpparmadillo-compile-errors-on-os-x-mavericks) I did the following:

```
# Update FLIBS in ~/.R/Makevars
FLIBS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran
#Re-Install from source
install.packages(c("Rcpp","RcppArmadillo","inline"),type="source")
#Restart R
```

this was JUST trying things out since I have NO `/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/` directory. In fact, all my `libgfortran*` files are here (At the macports dir):

```
>ls /opt/local/lib/gcc48/libgfortran.*
/opt/local/lib/gcc48/libgfortran.3.dylib       /opt/local/lib/gcc48/libgfortran.dylib
/opt/local/lib/gcc48/libgfortran.a       /opt/local/lib/gcc48/libgfortran.spec
```

and here `/opt/local/lib/gcc48/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/4.8.3/libgfortranbegin.a` and I have no `gfortran` file anywhere.

Then I tried the code [RccpvsR](http://brainchronicle.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/rcpp-vs-r-implementation-of-cosine.html) again and surprisingly, it worked!. Apart from the fact that I get a warning:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran'
```

because of course, it does not exists, but the function created by that code, `cosineRcpp`, runs with no problems.

Therefore, all that, to ask if anyone knows if I have to simlink the `libgfortran` files at `/opt/local/lib/gcc48/` as:

```
ln -s /opt/local/lib/gcc48/libgfortran.* /usr/local/lib/
```

and then remove/edit the line:

```
FLIBS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran
```

at  `~/.R/Makevars`

or if I have to install something new.

thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Are you by chance on OS X? You may want to ask in r-sig-mac; I think you need Xcode command-line tools or something.  The rcpp-devel list may help too.   I am on Linux where these things "just work".

Comment: Yes, I edited the question. I am in a Mac 10.9.5 and using the latest R version. I also have Xcode installed. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Check Simon's "R on Mac" page for gfortran. I think you may need to install something else.

Comment: Just installing Xcode is not sufficient. You now (since OSX 10.7 I think) need to additionally install Command Line Tools (from within Xcode). The version of gfortran offered at the ATT website is gfortran-4.2.3 and it warns you that most other versions are incomplete and specifically warns against using versions from HPC (whatever that might be.).

Comment: @BondedDust: I believe I have the Command line tools installed, since i have needed/used it in the past. I will check later at home, but I am pretty sure I have it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Short Answer

Just put the path to `libgfortran` into `FLIBS`, e.g.

```
FLIBS=-L/opt/local/lib/gcc48/
```

Or, symlink the files within to `/usr/local/lib/`, if you're comfortable with that. This solution is, however, quite brittle as it's easy to forget to update this path if you update `gfortran`, or move it to a different directory.

## Slightly Longer Answer

You can query `gfortran` for the path to `libgfortran.dylib` as e.g.

```
gfortran -print-file-name=libgfortran.dylib
```

You can just execute this directly in your `Makevars` file; e.g.

```
FLIBS = -L`gfortran -print-file-name=libgfortran.dylib | xargs dirname`
```

---

## Obsolete Long Answer

Try parsing an appropriate `FLIBS` directly from `gfortran` output.

First, some background. The `/usr/local/Cellar` directory is the default path used by [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), a package manager for OS X. Think of it as an alternative to `macports`.

Homebrew now provides `gfortran` and its associated libraries as part of the `gcc` package, and so the paths where it installs FORTRAN libraries has now changed. However, these can (in general) be discovered using `gfortran -print-search-dirs`. For example, on my system,

```
gfortran -print-search-dirs
```

will give me

```
install: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/
programs: =/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/bin/
libraries: =/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/lib/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../:/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/:/lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/:/usr/lib/
```

Split, and printed with R, I see:

```
[[1]]
[1] "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/"

[[2]]
[1] "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/"                                                                                    
[2] "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/"                                                                                    
[3] "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/"                                                                                          
[4] "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/"                                                                                
[5] "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/"                                                                                      
[6] "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/"
[7] "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/bin/"                                

[[3]]
[1] "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/"                                                                                
[2] "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/"
[3] "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/lib/"                                
[4] "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/"                                       
[5] "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../"                                                                       
[6] "/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/"                                                                                                                         
[7] "/lib/"                                                                                                                                                         
[8] "/usr/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/"                                                                                                                     
[9] "/usr/lib/"
```

In my case, `libgfortran` actually lives here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../
```

And so this is the path we want to pass to `FLIBS`. But, pulling that out is kind of a pain, so let's just tell `FLIBS` to use whatever paths are normally used by `gfortran`:

```
gfortran -print-search-dirs | grep ^libraries: | sed 's|libraries: =||'
```

This is nice, but we want the library paths in a format suitable for the compiler; ie, with `-L` prepended. Let's do that with `sed`:

```
gfortran -print-search-dirs | grep ^libraries: | sed 's|libraries: =||' | sed 's|:| -L|g' | sed 's|^|-L|'
```

This outputs (split for readability)

```
-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/
-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/
-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/lib/
-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/
-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/../../../
-L/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/
-L/lib/
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/
-L/usr/lib/
```

All together, this implies that the following should work for you, at least on OS X, but should (in general) work on any platform with `gfortran` (as long as it's on the `PATH`):

```
FLIBS=`gfortran -print-search-dirs | grep ^libraries: | sed 's|libraries: =||' | sed 's|:| -L|g' | sed 's|^|-L|'`
```

This isn't perfect, e.g. it will fail if you have spaces in your paths -- if you do, 1) you deserve what you get and 2) it should also be a 'relatively' easy fix.

Comment: Oh boy :)  Thanks for all that detail.  Should we update the corresponding question in the Rcpp FAQ?

Comment: @kevin Ushey: I knew about homebrew, but since I never used it I did not know that `/usr/local/Cellar ` is the default directory. Now, I like your short answer (it works) and I really, really like your long one (it also works). Many many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

A small tweak to the answer from @kevin-ushey (that at least I needed; I use Prezto) was adding single quotes to `grep '^libraries:'`, resulting in:

```
FLIBS=`gfortran -print-search-dirs | grep '^libraries:' | sed 's|libraries: =||' | sed 's|:| -L|g' | sed 's|^|-L|'`
```

Adding that line to my `~/.R/Makevars` file did the trick!