# Rcpp Compilation ERROR: 'clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.a'

Tags: r, rcpp, libconfig

I was trying to run this peace of code in R (credit to [the author](http://brainchronicle.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/rcpp-vs-r-implementation-of-cosine.html)):

```
require(Rcpp)
require(RcppArmadillo)
require(inline)
cosineRcpp <- cxxfunction( 
  signature(Xs = "matrix"), 
  plugin = c("RcppArmadillo"),
  body='
    Rcpp::NumericMatrix Xr(Xs);  // creates Rcpp matrix from SEXP
    int n = Xr.nrow(), k = Xr.ncol();
    arma::mat X(Xr.begin(), n, k, false); // reuses memory and avoids extra copy
    arma::mat Y = arma::trans(X) * X; // matrix product
    arma::mat res = (1 - Y / (arma::sqrt(arma::diagvec(Y)) * arma::trans(arma::sqrt(arma::diagvec(Y)))));
    return Rcpp::wrap(res);
')
```

And got, after few fixes, the following error:

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! 
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libreadline.a'
make: *** [file5a681e35ebe1.so] Error 1
In addition: Warning message:
running command '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD SHLIB file5a681e35ebe1.cpp 2> file5a681e35ebe1.cpp.err.txt' had status 1
```

I used to use Rcpp a lot in the past. But between now and then my computer has been reformatted and all the installation re-done using homebrew.

I installed `cairo` with brew: `brew install cairo`

the `libreadline.a` error was solved with:

```
brew link --force readline
```

But the same did not work for `libfontconfig.a` since was already linked:

```
brew link --force fontconfig
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.11.1
To relink: brew unlink fontconfig && brew link fontconfig
```

I would have assumed that `fontconfig` is within `cairo`. In fact, when I type

```
brew install fontconfig
Warning: fontconfig-2.11.1 already installed
```

But the truth is that there is no `libfontconfig.a` at `/usr/local/lib/`:

```
ls /usr/local/lib/libfont*
/usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib 
/usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.dylib
```

Using the very questionable approach of going [here](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/libfontconfig.a.434524-0.html) and download it, the code runs, but still gives a the corresponding warning, since the file corresponds to a different os.x architecture (I did not found one for 10.9):

```
+ . + ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.a (2 slices)
```

So at this stage I am a little lost.

How do I install `libfontconfig.a` or find the 10.9 version?

In case is of any use, I have Xcode installed, I am on a Mac 10.9.5, 
and based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992066/rcpp-warning-directory-not-found-for-option-l-usr-local-cellar-gfortran-4-8) very nice and detailed answer my `~/.R/Makevars` file looks like:

```
CC=clang
CXX=clang++
FLIBS=-L/usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: I found this link: https://github.com/olarivain/iTunesServer/blob/master/libraries/HandBrake/contrib/libfontconfig.a , and the file in here works. Still, I would be interested in knowing if can be directly installed with Homebrew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your system setup is broken.  Neither R nor Rcpp have anything to do with clang (unless you chose clang as your system compiler) or fontconfig.

So start simpler:

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> evalCpp("2 + 2")
[1] 4
R>
```

This just showed that my system has a working compiler R (and Rcpp) can talk to.  We can it more explicit:

```
R> evalCpp("2 + 2", verbose=TRUE)

Generated code for function definition: 
--------------------------------------------------------

#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP get_value(){ return wrap( 2 + 2 ) ; }

No rebuild required (use rebuild = TRUE to force a rebuild)

[1] 4
R>
```

and R is clever enough not to rebuild.  We can then force a build

```
R> evalCpp("2 + 2", verbose=TRUE, rebuild=TRUE)

Generated code for function definition: 
--------------------------------------------------------

#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP get_value(){ return wrap( 2 + 2 ) ; }

Generated extern "C" functions 
--------------------------------------------------------


#include <Rcpp.h>
// get_value
SEXP get_value();
RcppExport SEXP sourceCpp_0_get_value() {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject __result;
    Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;
    __result = Rcpp::wrap(get_value());
    return __result;
END_RCPP
}

Generated R functions 
-------------------------------------------------------

`.sourceCpp_0_DLLInfo` <- dyn.load('/tmp/Rtmpeuaiu4/sourcecpp_6a7c7c8295fc/sourceCpp_2.so')

get_value <- Rcpp:::sourceCppFunction(function() {}, FALSE, `.sourceCpp_0_DLLInfo`, 'sourceCpp_0_get_value')

rm(`.sourceCpp_0_DLLInfo`)

Building shared library
--------------------------------------------------------

DIR: /tmp/Rtmpeuaiu4/sourcecpp_6a7c7c8295fc

/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB -o 'sourceCpp_2.so' --preclean  'file6a7c6d1fc2d6.cpp'  
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG    -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/tmp/Rtmpeuaiu4"    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -c file6a7c6d1fc2d6.cpp -o file6a7c6d1fc2d6.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o sourceCpp_2.so file6a7c6d1fc2d6.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
[1] 4
R>
```

and on that you see system details on my side (Linux, also using ccache) that will be different for you.

After that, try (Rcpp)Armadillo one-liners and so on.

Comment: All that you wrote worked perfectly on my system. Perhaps I should have started by removing the CC=clang ,  CXX=clang++ in `~/.R/Makevars` (was there by default, since I never typed it. Anyway, Thanks (as always) and thankfully Rcpp is now running as fast and nice as always. (Still, if I remove the simlink to readline or the libfontconfig.a file, it will not work, but....I will leave it running for now)

Comment: Also, I read the following from here: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html#make : "Use clang instead of gcc to compile your C++ code: it gives much better error messages. You can make clang the default by creating a .R/Makevars (linux and mac) or .R/Makevars.win (windows) file in your home directory that contains: `CXX=clang++`  ". This is why I first assumed that clang had something to do with Rcpp :).

Comment: Dr Wickham has a very unfortunate tendency to make statements that sounds as if they were universally true. As this proposal appears to have broken your system,  I suggest you complain to him. We make no such suggestion (but reference clang as one possible compiler on OS X).

Comment: Also, R does NOT create `~/.R/Makevars` so you must have copied it at some point.  Some time or other, we all fall for things said on these Interwebs ...

Comment: :) !! ok Dirk, so, what do you suggest? All that you wrote in your reply works just fine, and at the moment all my Rcpp code that I have tried is running (not only the one shown in my question). However, I rather have a "non-broken" R-system, of course. Therefore, anything you might suggest I am happy to try it, I mean, you wrote the package, so...

Comment: Yes, and the package works for everybody including nightly CRAN tests. I suggests you follow the R documentation on how to work with R and compilers.  We recently added some more text on to the [Rcpp FAQ](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.Rnw) -- so try searching in that Rnw source for OS X and follow the links, the published pdf is behind.  _Our package works, and we cannot set your system up for you_ but give you pointers.

Comment: thanks, and no worries, I was not asking  you to set my system, not at all.  I will try to optimise the system. Thanks again