# Geeting a ld: warning: directory not found for option when trying to download R package from source

Tags: r, gcc, bioconductor

I'm trying to download DESeq2 from Bioconductor, and I keep running into this issue when I have to download something from the source.

```
using C++ compiler: ‘Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX13.3.sdk’
clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/opt/R/arm64/include    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c DESeq2.cpp -o DESeq2.o
clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/opt/R/arm64/include    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/opt/R/arm64/lib -o DESeq2.so DESeq2.o RcppExports.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0 -L/opt/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lemutls_w -lquadmath -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I saw a bunch of other threads that ran into the same problem, but I wasn't able to fix my issue. I downloaded gcc through homebrew, and I downloaded gfortran separately too. I'm trying to create a symlink like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999874/mac-os-x-r-error-ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option?newreg=be02e72cc438453781d2195f4d907bf3) says. I modified it to essentially have it link to the executable for gcc-13, using this command:

`sudo ln -sf /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/bin/gcc-13 /usr/local/bin/gcc`

I also created a `.R` folder and inside created a `Makevars` file, with this as the contents

```
VER=-13
CC=gcc
CXX=g++$(VER)
CXX11=g++$(VER)
CXX14=g++$(VER)
CXX17=g++$(VER)
CFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion
CXXFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion
FLIBS=-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/13
```

One thing for this is that I do not know if this file is actually being used or not. But when I go to install the package, it outputs the same error, so I'm not entire sure what is going on. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Where is your gfortran installed? You should not just make a symlink to a gcc executabke, you should adjust your environment variables so that your path and library paths see the whole GCC installation including gfortran. Also, gfortran must be in the same major version. The file you show is all about C++. You have to point the linker to the right path for the libgfortran library. Also, show the exact commands you are running when getting the error.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response! I installed gfortran using homebrew, so when I run `which gfortran` I get `/opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran`. I installed gfortran yesterday, so I believe it should be the most updated version. I'm getting the error when I run `BiocManager::install("DESeq2")` in the R terminal, and it doesn't install as a result. As to modifying the environment variables, I'm not entirely sure how to do that. Thank you so much!