# Problem installing R package "ld: warning: directory not found for option "

Tags: r, gcc, clang, gfortran, macos-catalina

I'm trying to install the package gradientForest in R by using

```
install.packages("gradientForest", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

And I'm getting this error

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
```

I've already tried the answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999874/mac-os-x-r-error-ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option) , and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992066/rcpp-warning-directory-not-found-for-option-l-usr-local-cellar-gfortran-4-8/29993906#29993906) .

According to these threads, I've installed gcc using

```
brew install gcc
```

and my Makevars looks like

```
## With Rcpp 0.11.0 and later, we no longer need to set PKG_LIBS as there is
## no user-facing library. The include path to headers is already set by R.
#PKG_LIBS = 

## With R 3.1.0 or later, you can uncomment the following line to tell R to 
## enable compilation with C++11 (or even C++14) where available
CXX_STD = CXX17

VER=-9
CC=gcc$(VER)
CXX=g++$(VER)
CXX11=g++$(VER)
CXX14=g++$(VER)
CXX17=g++$(VER)
CFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion
CXXFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion
FLIBS=-L`gfortran -print-file-name=libgfortran.dylib | xargs dirname`
```

but unfortunately it does not change anything on the error I'm having.
My R version is 3.6.1 and I am on MacOS Catalina.

If somebody is able to help me, I would be very grateful.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Got the same compilation error. Manual re-installation of both Clang and GFortran solved my problem. The instructions I used: [R COMPILER TOOLS FOR RCPP ON MACOS](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/)

(on Catalina 10.15.3; R 3.6.2; RStudio 1.2.5)

Comment: I installed gfortran using the package installer located here: https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases

I am using a M1 Mac mini but was able to successfully install and run the build for Monterey (macOS 12) Intel. I did not try the experimental ARM build.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a snippet from R official docs on how to install R on Mac, and related errors:

```
CC = /usr/local/clang7/bin/clang
CXX = /usr/local/clang7/bin/clang++
CXX11 = $CXX
CXX14 = $CXX
CXX17 = $CXX
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion
CXX11FLAGS = $CXXFLAGS
CXX14FLAGS = $CXXFLAGS
CXX17FLAGS = $CXXFLAGS
and gfortran by (El Capitan)

FC = /usr/local/gfortran/bin/gfortran
FLIBS = -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0
  -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
or (Sierra or High Sierra)

FC = /usr/local/gfortran/bin/gfortran
FLIBS = -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16/6.3.0
  -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
or (Mojave or later)

FC = /usr/local/gfortran/bin/gfortran
FLIBS = -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0
  -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
(with lines broken here for legibility).

If using the C/C++ compilers from the Command Line Tools (which do not have OpenMP support) one will need to include

SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS =
SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS =
```

For more information visit the below link at 6.3.2

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html

This might help you.

Comment: Accept and upvote the answer, if it resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Updating the `FLIBS`
variable in `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/Makeconf` fixed this for me

https://medium.com/biosyntax/following-up-library-dependency-when-compiling-r-packages-89f191b9f227