# gfortran installation for MacOS ventura

Tags: r, macos, gcc, gfortran

I am trying to install an older version of Matrix package in R

```
remotes::install_version("Matrix", version = "1.6-1")
```

but got this error

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
> '-L/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0'
> ld: warning:
> directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib'  ld: library not
> found for -lgfortran clang: error: linker command failed with exit
> code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: *** [Matrix.so] Error 1 ERROR:
> compilation failed for package ‘Matrix’
>
> - removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/Matrix’
> - restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/Matrix’
>   Warning message: In i.p(...) :   installation of package
>   ‘/var/folders/9z/j49cg7ss6p95_prl4f15j9xw0000gn/T//RtmpsoKABI/remotes56a1226e875/Matrix’
>   had non-zero exit status

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610155/problem-installing-r-package-ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option) and [this tutorial](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/), installing gfortran 12.2 for MacOS ventura. I see that it is in /usr/local/gfortran now. But I got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your error messages have a mix of aarch64 and arm64, what kind of machine do you have

Comment: the architecture is arm64

Answer (score 2):

I changed FLIBS path into paths to gcc in this file /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/Makeconf fixed this for me

I followed this blogpost

https://medium.com/biosyntax/following-up-library-dependency-when-compiling-r-packages-89f191b9f227