# incompatible matrix dimensions: 50x1000 and 50x1000 ? why?

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm doing a job with RcppArmadillo and trying to multiply a arma::cx_mat with a arma::mat, they are both size of 50x1000. but it raises a error: 
error: matrix multiplication: incompatible matrix dimensions: 50x1000 and 50x1000 ?
why it happens? and what should I do ?

Comment: Been awhile since I've done matrix multiplication, but can't a 50x1000 matrix only be multiplied by a 1000x50 matrix? This is more of a math question than a programming one.

Comment: The inner dimension has to match, so a x b works with b x c, resulting in an a x c matrix.

Comment: i was not clear in the question, what i want is the numerical multiplication, like c11 = a11*b11, c12=a12*b12, ...

Comment: If you want element-wise multiplication, use `%` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner dimensions need to be the same to take the matrix product. This would be true if you transposed the second matrix.

To multiply them element-wise (Hadamard product) with Rcpp, see 
 [Element-Wise Matrix Multiplication in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917023/element-wise-matrix-multiplication-in-rcpp).

Comment: i was not clear in the question, what i want is the numerical multiplication, like c11 = a11*b11, c12=a12*b12, ...

Comment: Oh, OK. Updated.